# How to change font color in R Markdown Powerpoint

Tags: r, markdown, powerpoint

I am using `R Markdown` to create a PowerPoint presentation and would like to change the font color in one of the slides. I am wondering if that's possible? It applies to only one slide so can't change in PowerPoint template. All the solutions I have found so far seem to be for `HTML` and `PDF` documents only.

- **CSS for html document**

```
---
title: "Example"
author: ""
date: "09/07/2020"
output:
  powerpoint_presentation
---


## R Markdown

<span style="color: red;">
This is an R Markdown presentation. 
I would like this text in red.
</span>
```

- **LaTex for pdf**

```
---
title: "Example"
author: ""
date: "09/07/2020"
output:
  powerpoint_presentation
---


## R Markdown

\textcolor{red}{
This is an R Markdown presentation. 
I would like this text in red.}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using {officedown}  an {officer} packages as suggested in [chapter 8.3 of Rmarkdown Cook book.](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/word-officedown.html)

1- Use the `officedown::rpptx_document` document output

2- Load `officedown` and `officer` packages

3- create the style to apply to the individual element in a chunk with `fp_text()`

4- Apply the style with in line code

```
---
title: Style text with officedown
output:
  officedown::rpptx_document: default
---

`` `{r setup, include=FALSE}

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

library(officedown)
library(officer)

ft <- fp_text(color = 'red', bold = TRUE)
`` `

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown presentation. 
`r ftext("I would like this text in red", ft)`.
```